# xcode create constant/variable as a build setting?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a URL used multiple times in my code and would like to centralize it into something like a build setting constant/variable. How would I go about accessing a build setting from my code? And is this the right thing to do?

Thank you.

Comment: How about defining the URL as an user macro in the IDE and percolate it to the build environment ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Constants.h

static NSString * const myStackURL = @"http://stackoverflow.com/users";
```

or

```
#define myStackURL @"http://stackoverflow.com/users"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do, essentially, is import a header that defines a constant into every one of your other files. The easiest way to do this is to stick it in *(application name)-Prefix.pch* in the Supporting Files group in the project navigator. Anything defined in this precompiled header can be used by any other file. From Programming iOS 5 by Matt Neuburg:

> The precompiled header is a device for making compilation go faster.
>   It’s a header file; it is compiled once (or at least, very
>   infrequently) and the results are cached (off in /var/folders/) and
>   are implicitly imported by all your code files. So the precompiled
>   header should consist primarily of #import directives for headers that
>   never change (such as the built-in Cocoa headers); it is also a
>   reasonable place to put #defines that will never change and that are
>   to be shared by all your code.